# passing a class instance as a parameter to a method in python

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    age = None
    gender = None
    weight = None

    def ___init__(self, age, gender):
        self.age = age
        self.gender= gender

class RunMain:
    person = Person()
    collect = CollectData()

    collect.getAge(person)
    collect.getGender(person)

    print person.age
    print person.gender

class CollectData():
    def getAge(self, person):
        person.age = 22
    def getGender(self, person):
        person.gender = 'Male'
```

I just did this in a hurry and I didn't use a compiler so there could be errors but my question is does Python allow you to send a class instance to a function?  Once we have the class instance, can i set the variables in that instance?

I could do this in C# and I've been programming in C# for a long time.  I just don't know how this works in Python and I couldn't find anything in any of the books that I've been through.

Comment: "my question is does Python allow you to send a class instance to a function" - sure, you can do that, class instances are first class objects. So are classes and functions, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  I was trying to find a way to edit my post.

Comment: Note that `getAge` and `getGender` are bad names for two reasons: 1. Python uses `lowercase_with_underscores` for methods; and 2. they **set** the attributes.

Comment: Of course you can. Why didn't you try it??

Comment: @jonrsharpe Python doesn't use `snake_case`, we do. Python uses whatever you tell it to use, it's just a common practice, a convention, to use `snake_case` for function and variable names.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen you're right, it would be more accurate to say that [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *recommends* that style.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think we have reached an agreement here.

Comment: BTW, that `__init__` method has a typo: it has **3** leading underscores instead of 2.

Comment: @jonrssharpe I can't change my style because I've been using that for the past 10 years.  I am just invested in that style so much that Python has to adjust to me :).

Comment: __init__ as I mentioned, I didn't use a compiler.  I just typed the code in here so I had a typo there but thanks for catching that PM 2Ring

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I tried it and explained in my post why it did not work and why I thought it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I rewrote your code a little so you can run it:

```
class Person:
    age = None
    gender = None
    weight = None

    def ___init__(self, age, gender):
        self.age = age
        self.gender= gender



class CollectData():
    def getAge(self, person):
        person.age = 22
    def getGender(self, person):
        person.gender = 'Male'



class RunMain:
    person = Person()
    collect = CollectData()

    collect.getAge(person)
    collect.getGender(person)

    print person.age
    print person.gender


RunMain()
```

You can run it here: https://repl.it/BBww

I think are asking whether the class instance passed in gets mutated. And yes it does just like in c#.  Why would you expect otherwise?

Strange idiom, though to use getAge() and getGender() to mutate those values.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  This was one of my questions and I figured this out by trial & error.  I didn't think it worked because I kept getting None for the value when I printed the values.  The code I wrote here was just as an example and it is not the code that runs.  I just wrote it as an example to learn.  I am not running this code.  I just wanted to get the theory of how class instances are treated.  Thanks for your help.  I appreciate you taking the time to come up with that example and I certainly appreciate the link because I will be using it for testing.